# Match text in another dataframe and fill missing columns with recognized entity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spacy

I want to fill missing Nan in a dataframe with recognized keywords from another dataframe.

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'models': ['A3', '520', 'clio3', 'C3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['I am selling a Citroen C3', 'I sell my Audi A3'], 'model': [np.nan, np.nan]})
```

**Update**: 
this case

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['I am selling a BMW 520 with good condition', 'I sell my Audi very good', 'clio3 for sale'], 'model': [np.nan,'A3', np.nan]})
```

should not replace 'A3'.

[image]

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if need avoid extract values in substrings with `word boundaries`:

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex and words boundaries with joined values by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df1['models'])
df2['model'] = df2['description'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df2)

                 description model
0  I am selling a Citroen C3    C3
1          I sell my Audi A3    A3
```

**Difference**:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['I am selling a Citroen C3', 
                                    'I sell my Audi A3', 
                                    'I sell my Audi A31']})


pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df1['models'])
df2['model1'] = df2['description'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
```

Solution with no word bounaries should return wrong matched values:

```
pat = '|'.join(df1['models'])
df2['model2'] = df2['description'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df2)

                 description model1 model2
0  I am selling a Citroen C3     C3     C3
1          I sell my Audi A3     A3     A3
2         I sell my Audi A31    NaN     A3
```

Comment: give m a sec for difference

Answer (score 2):

Use [`s.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a pattern:

```
df2.model=df2.description.str.extract(r'({})'.format('|'.join(df1.models)),expand=False)
print(df2)
```

---

```
                 description model
0  I am selling a Citroen C3    C3
1          I sell my Audi A3    A3
```

Where:`r'({})'.format('|'.join(df1.models))` gives `'(A3|520|clio3|C3)'`